# Topic of the Week idea for Outdoors.

Tags: feature-request, site-promotion

I've seen the idea of the **Topic of the Week** on some Stack Exchange sites. I think it would be the great idea to animate this site. First it would encourage existing users to ask more questions. Second, it could drive new users to the site.

For example, when the **geocaching** would be the topic of the week, that fact should be posted on both GeoCaching and OpenCaching foras. The same applies to other topics.

Comment: I like it.  I'll see if we can make this happen.

Comment: @RussellSteen Any update on this?

Comment: I think this is already being done http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/292/topic-of-the-week-winter-is-coming